# read data from text file and remove all newline space and show in console in c++

Tags: c++

```
fstream mfile;
string word = "";
string remove_space="";
char c;
```

//reading from the file

```
mfile.open("pin.txt");//reading from the file
if (mfile.is_open())
{
    while (!mfile.eof())
    {
        mfile.get(c);
```

//concatenating the data from file into string

```
        word = word + c;  
    }
}
for (int i = 0; word[i]; i++)
{
    if (word[i] != ' ')
        remove_space = remove_space + word[i];
}
```

// spaces between words are removed but newline spaces are remain

```
cout << remove_space;
```

Comment: Why not read the input file character by character, and only output the character if it shouldn't be ignored?

Comment: Also please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 1):

The for loop

```
for (int i = 0; word[i]; i++)
{
    if (word[i] != ' ' || word[i]=='\n')
        remove_space = remove_space + word[i];
}
```

will not ignore the newline characters as you intend it to. Every time the loop reaches a newline character, it will be concatenated to the remove_space string.
You have to invert the equals operator: `word[i] == '\n'` to `word[i] != '\n'`. This isn't enough, however, because the if statement will check the first expression, and if it is true, it will ignore the other one. That means that it never gets to check if the character is a newline character. To solve this, you have to also invert the || operator, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; word[i]; i++)
{
    if (word[i] != ' ' && word[i] != '\n')
        remove_space = remove_space + word[i];
}
```

Comment: i have edit the code now review it i want that my code will display in one single line with out new line spaces

Comment: i've edited the answer, I hope the solution is more clear now. You simply wrote == instead of !=.

Comment: I tried but it is still showing the code in multiple lines

Comment: whoops. it's not enough to only invert the equals operator, you also have to flip the or operator. edited answer again.

Comment: i had use or operator but still no progress